# Cannot start JBoss 7.0.2 on Windows

Tags: windows, exception, jboss, jboss7.x, java.util.logging

I have a problem starting JBoss version 7.0.2 on Windows 7. I got this error also with Jboss 7.1.1 and 7.1.0 so I thought reverting to an older and more stable version would do the trick, but with no use.

Below is the problem - the LogManager was not properly installed.

[image]

I have not deployed anything that might use the logger or anything, I just run standalone.bat after a clean install and restart. I found [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1) but it seems to be resolved...

The funny thing is, I was able to start it from Eclipse (both Indigo and Juno EE version).

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: See also https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7427

Comment: Have you altered your standalone.conf.bat? You could try adding `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager`.

Comment: Yes, Vadzim you are right. The problem was with the jmx parameters. Since I did not need them anymore, I removed them from JAVA_PROPERTIES and it started fine - 7.0.2 and also JBoss 7.1.1. Maybe you want to answer the question properly so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the JMX parameters in the JAVA_OPTS. After I removed them, it started with no exceptions.