# JBoss 7.1.x wont start in Fedora 18

Tags: java, jboss, fedora

Here is a problem - JBoss throws the following an error at startup :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:60)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeRepositorySelector.<clinit>(BridgeRepositorySelector.java:42)
```

this is an old issue and i believe was fixed [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7427) a while ago. The difference here that i do not have jmx parameters at startup.

The things I've been noticed:

- same error pops up in both Oracle's and OpenJDK jdk
- adding parameter -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager to the /bin/standalone.conf as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531004/cannot-start-jboss-7-0-2-on-windows) just generates the same error (not ClassNotFound as should be expected)
- i also tried to move jboss-logmanager-xxx.jar to /bin directory but no luck

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Oracle JDK? There is a bug in OpenJDK.

Comment: the latest one - got it today

Comment: It worked on Oracle JDK 1.7.0_11 for me. OpenJDK it definitely doesn't work on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when i returned back to Oracle's JDK and changed this new jdk in alternatives.

Comment: The latest IcedTea release seems to fix the issue.